# Sesame server support for SPIN

Tags: sesame, spin-rdf

I am new to SPIN, I read the documentation and I looked up some examples but I would like to start working with it.

I saw some tools from http://topquadrant.com for SPIN but I've been working with openrdf-sesame server for a while and I would like to stick with it.

I read the documentation from http://rdf4j.org/doc/4/programming.docbook?view
and I saw that there is a beta version of the SpinSail in the API... but I could not find anywhere on the website specified that the openrdf-sesame.war server has a SPIN processor or not.

Is it possible to use SPIN functionalities (adding rules, adding constraints, making inferences etc) with sesame's quadstore? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use the Workbench to create a new repository, and making sure that you pick a repository type that includes SPIN reasoning (there's a dropdown menu, the options with SPIN support should be fairly obvious). In other words it works similarly to how you create repositories with other types of reasoning support.

Comment: I was using an older version of the workbench and sesame (2.8.x) with JAVA 7 running on my machine and that's why I could not see the repository. I downloaded version 4.1.1 and I also had to install JAVA 8 and yes I found the repository with SPIN support. I am developing on JAVA 7 and I can't switch to JAVA 8 but thank's anyway.

Comment: @whitefang1993 we're bringing out a backport of the SPIN functionality in Sesame 2.9 in a few weeks, which is Java 7.