# How can I load SPARQL/SPIN constraints and constructors created in TopBraid Composer for use in Sesame within a SPIN-capable repository?

Tags: sparql, rdf, sesame, topbraid-composer, spin-rdf

I have successfully generated and tested SPIN constraints (using SPARQL `ASK` queries) within an OWL/RDF ontology using TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition version 5.1.1.  I would now like to test these SPIN constraints in Sesame.  How can I get my SPIN constraints, class definitions, property definitions, and test individuals contained in an OWL ontology authored in TopBraid COmposer Maestro Edition into Sesame?

I'm using Sesame OpenRDF Workbench:

```
System Information
Application Information
Application Name    OpenRDF Workbench
Version 4.1.2
Runtime Information
Operating System    Windows 8.1 6.3 (amd64)
Java Runtime    Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.8.0_91)
Process User    Greg
Memory
Used    357 MB
Maximum 3463 MB
```

My constraints, classes, properties, and example individuals are contained in one RDF file under TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition.

I've tried using the Sesame Open RDF workbench `Modify/Add` command to pull in the RDF file generated by TopBraid Maestro Edition, but I get an error that appears to be related to a blank node:

> `javax.servlet.ServletException: org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: org.openrdf.sail.SailException: org.openrdf.query.QueryEvaluationException: Multiple statements for pattern: _:node1alqlr2eix590 http://spinrdf.org/sp#where null`

Perhaps I'm not exporting from TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition correctly?  I used a generic export of the RDF file to the file system in TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition, and I used the Sesame OpenRDF workbench add RDF File / RDF Data File command, resulting in the above error message.

To preempt some possible answer directions which would not help in my particular case:

1. I specifically want to use SPIN constructors and constraints, not
   SWRL or another rule language.
2. Although I was successful in TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition and appreciate the help I got from TopQuadrant, I cannot afford the TopBraid Live license required to use my SPIN constructors and constraints while interacting with other computers.  (TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition has a SPARQL endpoint, but that endpoint is only accessible from the host machine via localhost.)  I also want to determine if the Sesame implementation imposes some of the same restrictions on SPIN constraints and constructors that the TopBraid tools do.

Comment: Have you chosen a Sesame repository type with SPIN reasoning?  See [Sesame server support for SPIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738282/sesame-server-support-for-spin).

Comment: Yes, Scott, I selected an In Memory Store with SPIN+RDFS support.  I meant to include that in my question, but it didn't make it in.  The error message references Sail which supplies the Sesame implementation of SPIN, I believe.  Also note that the RDF file I'm trying to import is relatively small with under 2000 facts total, so in memory should not be a problem.

Comment: The SPIN support in Sesame / RDF4J is still beta and it's quite possible that you've uncovered a bug. Could you submit a bug report with relevant details (including the actual RDF/SPIN file that causes the problem)?

Comment: Thanks Jeen Broekstrat.  The work is for the DoD.  Although it's not classified, I should still take a couple things out of the ontology and make sure it still has the same problem.  I can preserve one of the constraints without worrying about disclosing something I shouldn't.  Then, assuming the problem persists, I can submit the bug report.  If the problem doesn't persist, that itself would be an important clue.

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting, TallTed.  I'll try to get it formatted better upon submission next time.  I'm not yet familiar with the question formatting tools.

Comment: Issue reported at https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/195

Comment: Thanks for linking my issue report, Jean Broekstra.  I should do that myself in the future.  Still a newbie...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully load RDF from TopBraid Composer Free Edition by modifying how I was adding the RDF in Sesame and by avoiding instantiating classes in the RDF, deferring that by using a `SPARQL UPDATE` query executed usping the workbench Modify/SPARQL Update instead.

Specifically, the error message in my original post resulted from "use base URI as context identifier".  This option is checked by default in Sesame Workbench Modify/Add.  Unchecking this box loads my RDF into the default graph/context where it worked.  Technically, I regard this as avoiding the problem rather than solving it since the RDF should have been able to load into a named graph/context as well, but I don't need that for now.

[Add RDF Into Default Graph/Context by Unckecking "use base URI as context identifier"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I54P2.png)

After clearing this error, my RDF file had instantiated some individuals which caused trouble upon loading into Sesame.  I avoided this problem by using a SPARQL Update query to create my test instantiations.  Here's an example:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sxxicc: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheck#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX sp: <http://spinrdf.org/sp#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX smf: <http://topbraid.org/sparqlmotionfunctions#>
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX spl: <http://spinrdf.org/spl#>
PREFIX spin: <http://spinrdf.org/spin#>
PREFIX arg: <http://spinrdf.org/arg#>
PREFIX SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals#>
PREFIX sxxicci: <http://www.disa.mil/dso/a2i/ontologies/PBSM/Interface/SXXIComplianceCheckIndividuals#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

INSERT DATA
{
   sxxicci:TestPub7Proposal a sxxicc:Pub7Proposal ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem005 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem017 ;
           sxxicc:pub7ProposalHasDataItem sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem102 .

   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem005 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem005 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue "S"^^xsd:string .

   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem102 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem102 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue "AF  881234"^^xsd:string .

   sxxicci:testPub7Proposal_DataItem017 a sxxicc:Pub7DataItem017 ;
           sxxicc:pub7DataItemHasStringValue "U"^^xsd:string .
}
```